# How does one generate documentation with doxygen while using c++20 modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, doxygen, c++-modules

Doxygen (version 1.9.7) does not currently support C++20 modules, as discussed in these issues([7261](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7261),[9116](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9116),[8772](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8772)).

When I tried, classes defined in module interface units did not appear in the resulting documentation.

Example module interface unit (with comments for documentation):

```
export module hello_world;
///
///\brief Hello World Class 
///
///Prints hello world
///
export class HelloWorld{
public:
    /**
    @brief Print Method 
    @param [in] no input parameters
    @param [out] no output parameters
    */
    static void print();
};
```

One work around that I have tried is to use the script below to create a "header" file (for example with *.h* extension) from each module interface (for example with *.cppm* extension). Importantly, there are no files with *.h* extension which are compiled - I am using make and gcc - [see discussion on choosing extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html)). The files with ".h" extensions are then included by doxygen (`FILE_PATTERNS = *.h` in Doxyfile).:

```
#!/bin/bash
module_extension=cppm
module_files=$(ls *.$module_extension)
for module_file in $module_files; do
    awk '{gsub("^export module", "//export module");gsub("^export class", "class")}1' "$module_file" > "${module_file%.$module_extension}.h" 
done
doxygen
```

This works as a "quick and dirty" approach. Are there more formal solutions or patches available? Surprisingly I could not find other solutions using my favorite search engine. Pointers would be most welcome.

Comment: Even if modules were introduced in c++20 2 out of the 3 major compilers don't fully support them yet. 3rd party tools (like doxygen) support will be even more behind.